# Xcode force build to locked device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

(Especially if a device is configured to trust a computer)

Is it possible to have Xcode force build to a locked device?

Comment: Not possible. Why not disable password locking on a development device?

Comment: I have a 5 minute delay on lock on my device, which helps.

Comment: i code on the go a lot, traveling light on the subway with my personal iPhone. i don't like having to disable the minute lock, or keeping to fudge with quasi-working touchID to wake it up

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of iOS is different than Android.  Eclipse (ADT) will install to a locked device.

Xcode, on the other hand, will not.

Comment: ADT is not relevant to the question at all.

Comment: Yes it is, as it's a comparison to how it's handled in Android, if an Android developer were learning iOS they might make this mistake.